# XML in HTML with FadeIn-Effects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

I am currently working on a banner with different texts in different languages. The banner has to be HTML (+CSS) and JS/jQuery. I though about going with an XML for the multilingual part.

Here's my html (part of it):

```
<script type="text/javascript" language='javascript' src='./js/jquery-2.1.0.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src='./js/xmltranslation.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language='javascript' src='./js/jquery.lettering.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language='javascript' src='./js/jquery.textillate.js'></script>
.
.
.

<h1 id="title" class="tlt" data-in-effect="fadeInLeft"></h1>
```

My solution with the XML file is done per jQuery:

```
$(function() {
var filename = location.pathname.substring(location.pathname.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
filename = filename.split(".")[0];
var language = 'de';
$.ajax({
    url: 'content.xml',
    success: function(xml) {
        $(xml).find(filename).each(function(){
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            var text = $(this).find(language).text();
            $("#" + id).html(text);
        });
    }
});
```

});

That works great so far. It displays the right phrases at the right container.

But I want to use the "fadeInUp" etc. effects, found in the jquery.textillate.js library (https://github.com/jschr/textillate).

They work great, if I have a text in the tag:

```
<h1 id="title" class="tlt" data-in-effect="fadeInLeft">Test</h1>
```

The test is fading in smoothly. But it isn't working because of the XML parsing. I think, the XML parsing is done after the page is loaded, while the Fade in effect takes place, when the page is rendered.

Has anybody a better solution? I already thought about parsing the XML with jQuery or JS and put the whole page between a -Tag and output the html parts with

```
document.write
```

but since other people in my company who only have basic html skills should work with the files aswell, I would prefer another solution.

Or does anybody know another fade in-Effect library?

Edit:

My solution (adding in the JQuery XML parsing):

```
$("#" + id).html(text).hide().fadeIn(1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [this library](http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/). It's worked for me when dynamically populating pages before. you just need to make the element hidden until page load. So an easy way might be to set the elements opacity to 0 then use the setTimeout function then add the class you want to the element. an example:

```
setTimeout(function(){
$('foo').addClass(animate fadeIn);
},100);
```

Comment: Hi
I tried it but it isn't working. It adds the class perfectly but still no effect. I actually used the same animate.css, jquery.textillate.js only makes the addition of another tag possible to keep the overview.